# How to get the quantity today reminders using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

Could not find a solution on the Internet! These code not work!

```
tell application "Reminders"
    get count (reminders whose due date is (current date))
end tell
```

Thanks!

Comment: That code matches dates down to the minute. Try matching ranges of dates, e.g. from midnight today up to but not including midnight tomorrow.

Comment: Until it turns out (((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `due date` of a `reminder` will probably never match as the `due date` is expressed as e.g. `date "Wednesday, December 4, 2019 at 5:00:00 PM"` and `(current date)` will be expressed as e.g. `date "Wednesday, December 4, 2019 at 11:03:13 AM"`, so unless this is run precisely at e.g. `date "Wednesday, December 4, 2019 at 5:00:00 PM"`, your `get count ...` as formed will not match.

I'd target the `date string` of `(current date)`, e.g. "Wednesday, December 4, 2019", however **Reminders** doesn't understand `date string of due date` even though `due date` is expressed as a *date object*.

So, one way to get a `count` is to make a `list` of the `due date` of every `reminder` and then evaluate the `date string` of each against `date string of (current date)`, using the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
tell application "Reminders"
    set ddList to the due date of every reminder
end tell

set ds to the date string of (current date)

set c to 0
repeat with d in ddList
    if d does not contain missing value then
        if date string of d contains ds then
            set c to c + 1
        end if
    end if
end repeat

return c
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).</sub>